# Please Help ERROR:This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided

Tags: solidity, dapps, web3.py, typescript, walletconnect

[image]

[image]

Please Help ERROR:This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided  am trying to get my header use dapps activateBrowserWallet
how do i solve this thanks in advance here's my code

When I save, I get :" TS2746: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided."

Here is the txs for my header:  THe issue is here: at line 13   I have attached image of the error at the react Host

import { useEthers } from "@usedapp/core"

export const Header = () => {
const {account, activateBrowserWallet, deactivate} = useEthers()

```
const isConnected = account !== undefined

return(
    <div>
        {isConnected ? (
            <button color="primary">
                onClick={deactivate}
                Disconnect
            </button>
        ) : (
            <button color="primary"
                onClick={() => activateBrowserWallet()}>
                Connect
            </button>
        )
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

here's my app.tx :

import React from 'react'
import { ChainId, DAppProvider } from "@usedapp/core"
import {Header} from "./components/Header"
function App() {
return (
<DAppProvider config={{
supportedChains: [ChainId.Kovan, ChainId.Rinkeby]
}}>

Hi!

export default App;

Comment: The `>` on line 11 probably should go at the end of line 12.